# Android scroll view does not work well fits on the screen when it should not

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

My project is to create the email field dynamic , in the sense that I can have one, two , and others. So I thought about putting the whole right side with the details in a ScrollView . The problem is that the scroolview never appears , is not scrollable and can not figure out what is wrong ,I would not want that would fit onto the screen but you can scroll . can someone help me ? thanks so much

[image]

**main.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/user" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7" 
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="21" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="10" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/labelname"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="3"
                            android:background="@color/gray"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_person"
                            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                            android:text=" Name"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize_label" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/name"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="7"
                            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:hint="Nome"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="10" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/labelsurname"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="3"
                            android:background="@color/gray"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_person"
                            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                            android:text=" Surname"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize_label" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/surname"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="7"
                            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:hint="Surname"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelemail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_email"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:text=" E-Mail"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize_label" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailHome"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="E-Mail"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailWork"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="E-Mail"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailOther"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="E-Mail"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailMobile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="E-Mail"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelnumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_dial_pad"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:text=" Telefono"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize_label" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Number"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/color_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_save"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="#78858B"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/color_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#78858B"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/color_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#78858B"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/color_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="#78858B"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hey set your scrollview height to some static value so it will display you exactly that height and also it will be scrollable.

Comment: I tried to include as an example 700dp , ok but not scrolling , remains fixed

Comment: means in that 700dp is your all content can be visible ? set your height to 100 dp than check it.

Comment: Does not work , I believe that putting a fixed size is not useful for me because the ScrollView has the weight and then you have to adapt to the page on any device I use

Answer (score 0):

Try to only use ScrollView for various email EditText and also given weight to ScrollView so it will taken rest space for showing multiple email EditText :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.90"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/user" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/labelname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/gray"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_person"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:text=" Name"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize_label" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="Nome"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/labelsurname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/gray"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_person"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:text=" Surname"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize_label" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/surname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="Surname"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelemail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_email"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text=" E-Mail"
                android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize_label" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fillViewport="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailHome"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="E-Mail"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailWork"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="E-Mail"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailOther"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="E-Mail"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailMobile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="E-Mail"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelnumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_dial_pad"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:text=" Telefono"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize_label" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Number"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/campaign_textfontsize" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/color_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_save"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="#78858B"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/color_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#78858B"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/color_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#78858B"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/color_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="#78858B"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I copied your example xml , but this is the result [link](http://it.tinypic.com/r/2565sao/8)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/feedback_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Your Feedback"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_feedback"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:typeface="serif" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/feedback_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Your Email Address"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_feedback"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/feedback_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Submit Feedback"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:typeface="monospace" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

see this code and analyze if it might helpful to you. and also scrollview must have one child .

Comment: the scrollview must have the weight

Answer (score 0):

**> > Take Linear layout as a parent, and scroll view as a child.

> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>                        android:orientation="vertical"
>                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
>
> ```
>     <requestFocus />
> </EditText>
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/feedback_email"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="10dp"
>     android:ems="10"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:hint="Your Email Address"
>     android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
>     android:padding="5dp"
>     android:textColor="#666"
>     android:typeface="serif"
>     android:background="@drawable/edittext_feedback"
>      />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/feedback_submit"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center"
>     android:layout_margin="10dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
>     android:padding="15dp"
>     android:text="Submit Feedback"
>     android:textColor="#666"
>     android:typeface="monospace" /> </LinearLayout> </ScrollView>
> ```
>
> **